# Fetch distinct / different from previos row Data from MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a simple Table. It contains an ID, a Temperature and a Date. Every 10 Seconds a Sensor writes a Row with the measured Temperature-Value.

What I need is the Data, where the temperature changed. For Example:

```
ID, Temp, Date

1, 10, 2023-03-01_13_00_00
2, 10, 2023-03-01_13_00_10  <= Same as previos, should be filtered out
3, 11, 2023-03-01_13_00_20
4, 10, 2023-03-01_13_00_30
5, 10, 2023-03-01_13_00_40 <= Same as previos, should be filtered out
6, 10, 2023-03-01_13_00_50 <= Same as previos, should be filtered out
7,  9, 2023-03-01_13_01_00
```

Is it possible to do it in MySQL right away?

Comment: What version of MySQL? Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: If you are not yet using 8.0, a "self-join".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) function, but it requires MySQL 8+.

Consider the following data.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id int,
  temp int,
  dt timestamp  ) ;

insert into my_table values 
(1,10,'2023-03-01 13:00:00'),
(2,10,'2023-03-01 13:00:10'),
(3,11,'2023-03-01 13:00:20'),
(4,10,'2023-03-01 13:00:30'),
(5,10,'2023-03-01 13:00:40'),
(6,10,'2023-03-01 13:00:50'),
(7,9,'2023-03-01 13:01:00');
```

With LAG we can find the difference between current and next row.

```
SELECT id,
       temp,
       dt,
       LAG(temp, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id asc)  - temp as diff
FROM my_table
```

Result

```
id  temp    dt                 diff
1    10   2023-03-01 13:00:00   -10
2    10   2023-03-01 13:00:10    0
3    11   2023-03-01 13:00:20   -1
4    10   2023-03-01 13:00:30    1
5    10   2023-03-01 13:00:40    0
6    10   2023-03-01 13:00:50    0
7    9    2023-03-01 13:01:00    1
```

Final query. Get only the rows where diff <> 0

```
SELECT id,
       temp,
       dt
FROM (   SELECT id,
                temp,
                dt,
                LAG(temp, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id asc)  - temp as diff
         FROM my_table
    ) x 
WHERE diff <> 0;
```

Result

```
id  temp    dt
1    10  2023-03-01 13:00:00
3    11  2023-03-01 13:00:20
4    10  2023-03-01 13:00:30
7    9   2023-03-01 13:01:00
```

[Check this working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/NW2zpHzP)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field)